# thinking sphinx unknown type 'mysql'; skipping

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, thinking-sphinx

I'm using ts version 2.0.5, rails 3.0.9 and mysql2 0.2.11

When trying to create my indexes, using rake ts:index, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: source 'technical_core_0': unknown type 'mysql'; skipping.
```

My development.sphinx.conf contains:

```
source technical_core_0
{
  type = mysql
  sql_host = localhost
  sql_user = root
  sql_pass = 
  sql_db = ps_development
  sql_sock = /tmp/mysql.sock
  sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8
  sql_query_pre = SET TIME_ZONE = '+0:00'
  sql_query = SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE `technicals`.`id` * CAST(1 AS SIGNED) + 0 AS `id` , `orders`.`name` AS `author`, `technicals`.`id` AS `sphinx_internal_id`, 0 AS `sphinx_deleted`, 488243725 AS `class_crc`, IFNULL(`orders`.`name`, '') AS `author_sort`, `technicals`.`order_id` AS `order_id`, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`technicals`.`created_at`) AS `created_at`, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`technicals`.`updated_at`) AS `updated_at` FROM `technicals` LEFT OUTER JOIN `orders` ON `orders`.`id` = `technicals`.`order_id` WHERE (`technicals`.`id` >= $start AND `technicals`.`id` <= $end) GROUP BY `technicals`.`id`, , `orders`.`name`, `technicals`.`id`, `orders`.`name`, `technicals`.`order_id`, `technicals`.`created_at`, `technicals`.`updated_at` ORDER BY NULL
  sql_query_range = SELECT IFNULL(MIN(`id`), 1), IFNULL(MAX(`id`), 1) FROM `technicals` 
  sql_attr_uint = sphinx_internal_id
  sql_attr_uint = sphinx_deleted
  sql_attr_uint = class_crc
  sql_attr_uint = order_id
  sql_attr_timestamp = created_at
  sql_attr_timestamp = updated_at
  sql_attr_str2ordinal = author_sort
  sql_query_info = SELECT * FROM `technicals` WHERE `id` = (($id - 0) / 1)
}
```

Which is a bit odd as my database.yml file contains mysql2 and a root password.

Can you help me get past this stage? I tried also creating a sphinx.yml file with:

```
development:
 adapter: mysql2
```

But this also fails.

-- UPDATE --

I added this into the development initialisers file:

```
 ThinkingSphinx.database_adapter = :mysql2
```

Which gives error about only MySQL being supported.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you are compiling Sphinx you should specify the `--with-mysql` flag.

```
$ ./configure --with-mysql
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

You might need to specify the location of your MySQL library's include files.  For example on a fresh installation of OS X:

```
$ ./configure --with-mysql=/opt/local/include/mysql5
```

Comment: I shall try this later.. Thanks

Comment: Hi, this is running on rails3 - is it not enough to install the gem and include in the gem file?

Comment: No, Thinking Sphinx is an interface to Sphinx Search for Ruby, you need to install Sphinx on your system.

Comment: Ok, this is the bit I was missing... I hadn't realised I needed sphinx too. Installed and have another error but can sort that one. J

Answer (score 64):

As per the link [here](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/16073#issuecomment-11358273), you could simply do the following on homebrew (mac):

```
brew install sphinx --with-mysql
```

That worked for me :)

Comment: you can always `brew options [package name]` which will give u all available flag. in this case --mysql or --postgres

Comment: Had to `brew reinstall sphinx --mysql` since sphinx search was already installed.

Comment: the --mysql switch is deprecated. Use --with-mysql now.

Answer (score 3):

Also when installing on OSX via homebrew try this:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib /usr/local/mysql/lib/mysql
brew install --interactive sphinx
./configure
make
make install
exit
```

Answer (score 2):

The generated source looks correct - is it possible your version of Sphinx was compiled without MySQL support?

Comment: Hi Pat, I just installed the gem and can see in mysql listed. Perhaps I could try installing as a plugin but was sort of trying to avoid. It's quite frustrating now...